# Flash Builder "Burrito" : apk : invalid_apk , "parse error"

Tags: android

I've created an app in Flash Builder "Burrito". When I run the application there are no project warnings or errors. The .apk was compiled successfully.  The emulator is running Andorid 2.2. However, when I push the .apk to the emulator I get "Invalid Apk" error. 
I tried installing  it into Galaxy Phone (Android 2.2) , de time i got "Parse error "
any1 had the same problem resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

The .apk file generated by flashbuilder will not run successfully on the emulator. You have to generate an "emulator apk" using the adt.bat located in the bin directory of your AirSDK.

copy your files (appName.swf, appName-app.xml, cert_name.p12) to the bin directory and run the following command:

**adt -package -target apk-emulator -storetype pkcs12 -keystore cert_name.p12 appName.apk appName-app.xml appName.swf**

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/community/publishing/881/cpsid_88152.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be fixed in current build of the Flash Builder Burrito on labs.adobe.com.

For me, all my projects are working fine in the android/blackberry emulator, as well as on the android devices without setting specific options in the projects... or even with different compile-options.

Also the signing process now comes with a suitable wizard.

Answer (score 0):

I've no experience in coding with Flash Builder, but I heard that Flash Builder will wrap your classes in a specific apk. You'll find there is a "swf" file in the folder named "asset", as a matter of fact, Flash Builder is trying to release your application as its own flash format. so if you want to have your application running, the AIR runtime on the smartphone is must.

if you're learning android programing, it's much better to use eclipse and google adt as your develop environment, like most of us do :-)